# Switching order of supremum of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

This is a problem from Kincaid and Cheney book Numerical Analysis.  The question asks to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary sets and $f$ is a bounded real function on $A \times B$ then $$\sup_{a \in A}\sup_{b \in B} f(a,b)=\sup_{b \in B}\sup_{a \in A} f(a,b).$$  What I am struggling with is the following:  I have obtained that $$\sup_{a \in A}\sup_{b \in B} f(a,b) \leq M$$ and similarly $$\sup_{b \in B}\sup_{a \in A} f(a,b) \leq M$$ where $M$ is from $|f(a,b)| \leq M$ for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$.  I believe I need continuity and that $A$ and $B$ are closed.

Comment: Let $(a_n,b_n)\in A\times B$ such that $f(a_n,b_n)\to M$. Now,$$f(a_n,b_n)\le\sup_{b\in B}f(a_n,b)\le\sup_{a\in A}\sup_{b\in B}f(a,b).$$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thank you, that makes sense.